# ASP.NET MVC3 Multiple Databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello all:
I'm building an app using C#/MVC3/Razor which has a database configured in web.config. One of the requirements is to push the data to another database. is this doable within the MVC3 framework or should i just connect to the second database using standard methods/sql/?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a second connection string in your web.config and configure your ORM framework or whatever you are using to access those databases to use this second connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db1" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=dbName1;User Id=foo;Password=secret;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="db2" connectionString="Data Source=otherServerName;Initial Catalog=dbName2;User Id=bar;Password=secret;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Just one thing to remember: the [ADO.NET Connection Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) is per App Domain and per connection string meaning that two separate connection pools will be held in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="First_DB_Conn" connectionString="" providerName="Some_Provider" />
    <add name="Second_DB_Conn" connectionString="" providerName="Some_Provider" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This way you can add more connection to another dbs

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC itself contains nothing about databases (or any form of underlying persistence layer). In the MVC3 tools update some tooling for developers does make direct use of Entity Framework 4.1's "code first" capabilities.

But this is can be customised (eg. your own T4 templates or different scaffolding or completely ignored (manually write all persistence logic).  The latter would be needed if your application doesn't map to CRUD operations that the scaffolding assumes.

Doing it yourself could use multiple ADO.NET connections (with multiple connections strings in the .config file) or multiple ORM models for different databases.